# Rails console doesn't define "e" (in lowercase) letter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal, console, oh-my-zsh

I have very weird problem with own Rails console. I know, it sounds strange, but it (rails console) doesn't define "e" (in lowercase) letter.
Even I paste whole word. E.g: if I put something like "Every Exchange and else", it will show me: "Evry Exchang and ls".

I guess I have some problem with by zsh profile file (I use oh my zsh), but can't figure out what exactly is wrong.

If someone had same problem before, please help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you run any strange commands or commands you didn't fully understand recently?

Comment: Perhaps update the title of the question to something more helpful.

Comment: @EdCottrell this problem appeared a few months ago, I can't remember :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the missing binding of "e". Adding bind "e" : self-insert command to the inputrc file solved the problem.